# How do I get my Unity login screen back after installing Lubuntu Desktop on 14.04?

Tags: unity, lubuntu, lightdm

I have installed `lubuntu-desktop` and `xfce4` on a Ubuntu 14.04 installation.

After doing so, my login screen changed.

I have tried resetting my LightDM and attempted to modify the lightdm file, where nothing appears.

Comment: "My login screen changed" - what changed in the login screen? Please elaborate.

Comment: The "greeter" has been set to the Lubuntu login screen. It seems to be locked on Lubuntu when attempting to change it back.

Comment: I just tripped over what is likely the same thing today, so let me elaborate. I had standard Ubuntu up and running with the lightdm greeter. I needed to run a VNC server, and unfortunately VNC does not seem to play well with Gnome if you have a running desktop. I installed xfce as a workaround. Now when lightdm starts up, I get the standard lightdm background briefly. It is soon replaced by a background that appears to come from here: /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg
This is a file in the xfdesktop4-data package. Lightdm seems to believe that it is still setting up the original backgr

Comment: I am having the same issue. Take Ubuntu 14.04 and install xfce and the user will now have the xfce-blue wallpaper. All information I have found so far relates to setting the default lightdm backgroud, however this is still set to warty-final-ubuntu.png. On the login screen selecting guest or remote desktop shows the correct background wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

As the affected user change the background then log off. Lightdm should now be showing the chosen wallpaper.

Comment: Actually I rebooted and the behaviour returned. Ended up purging xfce from my install.